# Launch.json for VSCode/Haskell? Learning Haskell Plutus

Tags: plutus, haskell, vscode

I have VSCode all set up with the necessary Haskell plugins (except I have GHCI 9.x installed via Chocolatey and the plugins want 8.x, ouch! Unfortunately Chocolatey won't accept an 8.x "--version" number so I can't downgrade). But I can't find any place that shows me how to set up a proper `launch.json` file to support a Haskell debug session in VSCode.  I want to have a full-fledge debugger for my Haskell learning and I'm sure that I need to learn Haskell to be effective with Plutus.

Does anyone know how to craft a proper `launch.json` file so that I can use the VSCode IDE for Haskell debugging?

NOTE: I know about the Plutus playground but I would like a full-fledged IDE with a debugger for my Haskell learning. Also, the Plutus playground site is usable, except I **can't login** because the hand-off to GitHub for 3rd party authorization is currently broken. On that note, is there a GitHub repo for the playground so I can report that problem? I can't figure which of the many Plutus repos on GitHub are for the playground.

Comment: Don't use the Plutus playground site, it's quite outdated. Try to build the plutus playground with `nix` instead, it'd be a nice first exercise ( https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/tree/master/plutus-playground-server, https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/tree/master/plutus-playground-client )

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`phoityne-vscode`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/phoityne-vscode) for this.

There's a specific section called **Configuration** that shows how you can set your `launch.json` file up.